# Как перевести двумерный массив в одномерный?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте уважаемые хешкодовцы) помогите плз. У меня есть массив Int asd[100000][4]. Мне нужно перевести в одномерный массив qwe. Пример

```
         Дано                        должно получится
```

> ```
>       1  2   3  4             1  2  3  4  5  6  7
>    1  3  10  0  0             3  7  2  8  10 12 0
>
>    2  7  12  0  0
>
>    3  2   0  0  0
>
>    4  8   0  0  0
> ```

```
 P.s   1 2 3 4
      1
      2
      3
      4
```

Это номера ячеек, а не сам массив :)

.s Было бы хорош,о если бы без нулевых элементов), но это не особо важно. на выходе int[]

Comment: А какие элементы должны войти? Все, кто не ноль, или все до 1-го ноля? Или в результате должно быть 100000 * 4 элемента?

Comment: Все кто не ноль

Comment: а на выходе int[] или std::vector?

Comment: на выходе int[]

Answer (score 1):

Ну держите.

```
int size = 0;

// обходим и считаем не-нули
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    auto row = src[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (row[j])
            size++;
    }
}

// собираем результат
int[] dest = new int[size];
int curridx = 0;
// у вас там элементы складываются по столбцам, так что обходим в другом порядке
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        if (src[i][j])
            dest[curridx++] = src[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: какой сложный код) ну ничего разберусь

Comment: @VladD, а вот это

    auto row = src[i];

зачем?

Comment: @avp: старая привычка: для глупых оптимизаторов, которые не могли вынести общее подвыражение за цикл. С точки зрения современности уже не нужно.